# Asterisk ODBC: Why is "Last connection attempt: 1970-01-01 01:00:00"?

Tags: odbc, asterisk

I am using Asterisk 13.23.1 and I have configured ODBC successfully - everything is working fine.

But I wonder why `odbc show` always shows 
`Last connection attempt: 1970-01-01 01:00:00`

Why is the date never updated?

Comment: As this is not a programming question, it is off topic for stackoverflow.com

Comment: So that's why I get punished by a downvote?! And the kind person who answered my question, too?! :-(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Connection attempt filled by res_odbc only on re-connection.

So that just mean have been connected from first try.